# Problems in using PHP Soap Client

Tags: php, soap-client

I have this web service to access with this kind of configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <Executar xmlns="http://localhost/I9ProWebService">
      <Servico>string</Servico>
      <conteudoXML>string</conteudoXML>
    </Executar>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So I tried this:

```
$client = new soapclient('https://domain/webservice/I9ProWebService.asmx?WSDL');
printf($client->Executar("ListarTomador","<i9proerp><listar_tomador id_pessoa_corretor     =\"205\" /></i9proerp>"));
```

it shows this error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at I9ProWebService.Executar(String Servico, String conteudoXML) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: That error comes from the remote .NET Web service, not from PHP.

Comment: At soapUI this web service works...First time doing it at PHP...why is it so difficult?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or similar to encode the XML you are sending as your second parameter? That might be causing problems with the XML sent by the SOAP client.

**EDIT**: In order to see what XML the PHP SOAP client is sending and what it's getting back, you can use `$client->__getLastRequest()` and `$client->__getLastResponse()` and compare the results with your soapUI call.

Comment: It may be a reason. But why is giving this message:"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" ?

Comment: That would be a question for the developers of the service. It's a typically generic error that can be caused by a number of issues (just have a quick [Google for it](http://www.google.com/search?q="Object+reference+not+set+to+an+instance+of+an+object")), but those issues are in the .NET code and not in your PHP code.

Comment: Do I have to send 'xmlns="http://localhost/I9ProWebService"' as a parameter somewhere?

Comment: I tried to echo $client->__getLastRequest() but the application always stop before

Comment: That part should be handled by the SOAP client. Have a look at the request from PHP and compare it to what soapUI generates. The way to do that is put a try/catch around `$client->Executar()` and inspect the request in the catch block.

Comment: when I use var_dump($client->__getTypes() it shows: array(6) { [0]=> string(65) "struct ExecutarXML { string Servico; conteudoXML conteudoXML; }" [1]=> string(37) "struct conteudoXML { any; }" [2]=> string(68) "struct ExecutarXMLResponse { ExecutarXMLResult ExecutarXMLResult; }" [3]=> string(43) "struct ExecutarXMLResult { any; }" [4]=> string(57) "struct Executar { string Servico; string conteudoXML; }" [5]=> string(51) "struct ExecutarResponse { string ExecutarResult; }" } . How I could manage the "struct" ??

Comment: That's expected... it's the request and response that's important.

Comment: When I use "echo $client->__getLastRequest();" it returns nothing. It seems that this web service doesn´t accept anything. But it works in soapUi.

Comment: Are you checking the results in a browser? It's likely that it's returning some content but because it's XML your browser is trying to render it. Either view source or add `header('Content-Type: text/plain')` before you echo it out.

Comment: And the echo $e->getMessage() returns: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at I4ProWebService.ExecutarXML(String Servico, XmlNode conteudoXML)

Comment: Great cbuckley, you're right. It returns <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/I4ProWebService"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:ExecutarXML/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: But I don´t know why the parameters are not been sent.

Comment: Now my problem is to send "<i9proerp><listar_tomador id_pessoa_corretor=\"205\" /></i9proerp>" to <conteudoXML> as is defined as "struct"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://domain/webservice/I9ProWebService.asmx?WSDL", array("features" => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS, "encoding" => "utf-8","trace"=> TRUE));
$strVariavel = "<ns1:conteudoXML><i9proerp><listar_tomador id_pessoa =\"999\"/></i9proerp></ns1:conteudoXML>";
$soapvar = new SoapVar($strVariavel, 147);
$xml = $client->ExecutarXML(array('Servico'=>'ListarTomador','conteudoXML'=>$soapvar));
print_r($xml);
```

and voilá

The problem is that it returns and object and not a XML as I expected...

It returns:

```
 stdClass Object
 (
     [ExecutarXMLResult] => stdClass Object
         (
                 [any] => <i9proerp xmlns=""><listatomador id_pessoa="5251" nm_pessoa="nome1"  nr_cnpj_cpf="132132121332"/><listatomador id_pessoa="939" nm_pessoa="nome2" nr_cnpj_cpf="3213213123213"/></i4proerp>
            )
       )
```

So, I have to discover how to deal with it. Is it a case to open [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8520811/367456)?