# How to Parse a return of a Std Class object from a SoapClient command into a XML

Tags: php, xml, soap-client, stdclass

The response of a SoapClient command returned it:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ExecutarXMLResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [any] => <i9proerp xmlns=""><listatomador id_pessoa="5251" nm_pessoa="nome1" nr_cnpj_cpf="1"/><listatomador id_pessoa="939" nm_pessoa="nome2" nr_cnpj_cpf="2"/><listatomador id_pessoa="3285" nm_pessoa="nome3" nr_cnpj_cpf="3"/></i9proerp>
     )
 )
```

How I get the return into a XML?

Comment: [`$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($object->ExecutarXMLResult->any);`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing stdClass Object data in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522572/parsing-stdclass-object-data-in-php)

Comment: No, because it returns a XML inside that I want to separate and I can´t do.

Comment: It helped DaveRandom, thanks,  but appears an array.

Answer (score 0):

Assume

```
$obj = ... // result from soap, as stated above
$obj->ExecutarXMLResult->any (XML string)
```

Whether is a valid XML string, that's not part of this discussion.

Comment: How I transform the $obj into a XML string?